MAUI IOS publish fails .net8.0 BrowserEngineKit
I have problem when publish maui app with transporter. I recieve the following isue:
Invalid SDK usage. The following frameworks aren’t permitted for apps using an alternative web browser engine: [BrowserEngineKit]. (91017)
I think do not use "BrowserEngineKit", can someone know this issue and help to fix it?
I tried to remove BrowserEngineKit, but I do not know why it is used.

Same here, I can see in the build logs, but currently can't determine from where it's coming:
Tool xcrun execution started with arguments: clang++ -F  [...] -weak_framework BrowserEngineKit


I am currently experiencing issues while uploading my macOS app to the App Store. Previously, I was able to upload the application without any issues, and it was working fine. After I updated the .NET workload, I started encountering this problem.
Error : Invalid SDK usage. The following frameworks aren’t permitted for apps using an alternative web browser engine: [BrowserEngineKit]. (91017)
How to exclude the this package "BrowserEngineKit" ?

According to this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/21324 you can use the supplied workaround:
Add this to your project file (csproj):
<Target Name="DoNotLinkWithBrowserEngineKit" AfterTargets="_ComputeLinkNativeExecutableInputs">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_NativeExecutableFrameworks Remove="BrowserEngineKit" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

